# Convert UTC Date to Local Date (server's timezone) in java jdk8

Tags: java, date, datetime, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

I want to convert from utc java.util.date time (which is in UTC) to server's local time. we r using jdk8. how can i do this?

my requirement is, we are getting lastTime in UTC. We need to show a user friendly date in local timezone in the portal. Below is my code which is not working.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.Date;
private String getDateInString(Date lastTime) {
        Date in = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        LocalDateTime monthLdt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(in.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusMonths(1);
        Date monthAgo = Date.from(monthLdt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        LocalDateTime weekLdt = LocalDateTime.now().minusWeeks(1);
        Date weekAgo = Date.from(weekLdt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        LocalDateTime dayLdt = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);
        Date dayAgo = Date.from(dayLdt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        if (lastTime.before(monthAgo)) {
            return "Month ago";
        } else if (lastTime.before(weekAgo)) {
            return "Week Ago";
        } else if (lastTime.before(dayAgo)) {
            return "Day Ago";
        } else {
            LocalDateTime lastLdt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(lastTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
            String min = lastLdt.getMinute() + "";
            if (lastLdt.getMinute() < 10) {
                min = "0" + min;
            }
            return "TODAY," + lastLdt.getHour() + ":" + min;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use `java.time` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: You can use a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`, which both have a method `now()`, view some `java.time` documentation. It will serve you well...

Comment: That code looks correct, or close. What was your question, again, please? Even though I would have preferred to do all the comparisons in java.time, between `ZonedDateTime` objects. Also if run in the morning and last time was the evening before, so less than a full day ago, it seems it will yield like `TODAY,18:32` even though that was yesterday. I would also use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting the time.

Comment: lastTime we get as input is in UTC, we need to return friendly text as "Month ago", "Day ago", "Week Ago", if its today, we need to return "Today," followed by Hrs and Mins. like: Today, 11:30. Sorry, did not understand why we need to use DateTimeFormatter. Can you share the sample code?

Comment: @pal.nag Did I answer your question? Asking because it wasn’t that clear to me which but you had trouble with. My answer does show how `DateTimeFormatter` helps produce a string like `23:00` without us needing to concatenate the string “by hand” taking care of leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

### Go all-in on java.time

Two points:

1. Go all-in on java.time. When you receive an old-fashioned `Date`, convert it to `Instant` first thing and make further conversions and processing using java.time so you don’t need to deal with `Date`. This can save you quite a number of conversions and hence make your code simpler.
2. The class to use in java.time is `ZonedDateTime`. Since `Date` is a point in time, for a comparison that makes sense you also in java.time need a class that defines a point in time. `LocalDateTime` does not. A `ZonedDateTime` is a date and time in a time zone, so what we need for the local time (despite the class name `LocalDateTime`).

Also if your code from the question runs in the morning and last time was the evening before, so less than a full day ago, it seems it will yield like `TODAY,18:32` even though that was yesterday. I would also use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting the time.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");

private static String getDateInString(Date lastTime) {
    ZoneId localZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    
    ZonedDateTime lastDateTime = lastTime.toInstant().atZone(localZone);
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(localZone);
    
    ZonedDateTime monthZdt = now.minusMonths(1);
    ZonedDateTime weekZdt = now.minusWeeks(1);
    ZonedDateTime dayZdt = now.minusDays(1);

    if (lastDateTime.isBefore(monthZdt)) {
        return "Month ago";
    } else if (lastDateTime.isBefore(weekZdt)) {
        return "Week Ago";
    } else if (lastDateTime.isBefore(dayZdt)) {
        return "Day Ago";
    } else {
        String dayText;
        if (lastDateTime.toLocalDate().isBefore(now.toLocalDate())) {
            dayText = "YESTERDAY";
        } else {
            dayText = "TODAY";
        }
        String timeText = lastDateTime.format(TIME_FORMATTER);
        return String.format("%s, %s", dayText, timeText);
    }
}
```

To try it out the following two dates are from yesterday evening and this morning in my time zone, respectively:

```
    System.out.println(getDateInString(Date.from(Instant.parse("2021-04-21T21:00:00Z"))));
    System.out.println(getDateInString(Date.from(Instant.parse("2021-04-22T03:00:00Z"))));
```

Output was:

> ```
> YESTERDAY, 23:00
> TODAY, 5:00
> ```